# Have a cookie get deleted as soon as I leave the page on node

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am setting a cookie as soon as users access my node app like this:

```
app = require("express")();
httpServer = require("https").createServer(options,app);
cookie = require("cookie");

app.get('/site', function (req, res, next) {
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 res.cookie('active', 1, {
  httpOnly: true
 });
});
```

the cookie is stored so that just works fine. However, I want the cookie to be destroyed as soon as the user closes the browser, window, tab, etc. but its not. Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: if no Expires or max-age is set the cookie should be cleared as soon as the user browser closed.

Comment: well, it doesnt and my code looks exactly like above.

Answer (score 0):

As per cookie package example can you try following for your code ?

```
const app = require("express")();
const httpServer = require("https").createServer(options,app);
const cookie = require("cookie");

app.get('/site', function (req, res, next) {

 res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize('active', String(1), {
   httpOnly: true
 }));

 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the cookie gets set but is still there after I close the browser. Maybe its a firefox bug?